# Can't Install NuGet packages that require Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, nuget-package

I've been having problem installing NuGet packages that require Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1
I just recently installed it and when ever I try installing packages that need it, I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1' from source 'C:\Users\Sharon Umute\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\sermon\packages'.         0
```

I tried upgrading to Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2 and adding the path to Environment Variables but I keep getting the same error.
I've checked the path, the Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2 folder contains lib, tools, and Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.1.nupkg.
I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem when installing System.Net.Http. Simply remove the line that references Newtonsoft.Json in packages.config. It solved my problem

Comment: This WILL and DOES work, however it breaks the whole point of managing your referenced dependencies with NuGet. Shame on Newtonsoft for basically breaking NuGet in VS when their package is referenced!

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when trying to upgrade my packages and resolved it by upgrading to Newtonsoft.Json version 10.0.1.

In package manager run:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.1
```

After that, all my other packages were able to update.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

open packages.config, delete `<package id="Newtonsoft.Json"..>`, then refresh it
[image]